# How to make blob file downloadable?

Tags: 7, files

I have created a Module to make blob file available for Download in Drupal 7 .

Below my code for .module file

```
<?php

function blobfile_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['blobfile_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Blob Files Download'),
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function blobfile_block_view($delta) {    

      $query = db_select('health_policy_document_upload_dtl', h)->fields('h');
      $result = $query->execute();

      $content ='';
      while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {

          $filename = $record['Document_Name'];
          $file     = $record['Document'];
          $type     = $record['Document_Type'];
          $size     = filesize($file);


          header("Content-length: $size");
          header("Content-type: $type");          
          header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

          $content .= "<a href='#'>".$filename."</a>";
          $content .= "<br>";
      }

    return array(
      'subject' => t('Bids'),
      'content' => $content
    );   

}
```

Please guide me where I went wrong.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what you want to have built and what's happening?  You've built a block display that sets the response headers for a download (several times potentially), but then returns content for the block. You will need at least a hook_menu() and a router to return the files but exactly how that would works depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Here am trying to create a Block using custom code to display list of documents, which can be downloaded by clicking on the same. I can able to get result from database and display the same. but how to make those blob files available for download?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have already come up with a solution to upload the files and put them in the database, and that you have a good reason not to use Drupal's built-in file handling (I question that second assumption particularly given the reference to health policy but I'll grant it).

The block you created needs to just provide the list of links, but you should not set the headers there, just generate the links.  The link should probably be in the form of something like:  /custom_files/[filename]  (or something clearer based on your complete context.

First you need a [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) to define the menu router to get your files. Something like:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['custom_files/%mymodule_filename'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_filedownload',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'delivery callback' => 'mymodule_file_delivery',
  );
}
```

*You should also add some permissions handling here, the documentation on hook_menu() explains how that works.  Also read the section on deliver callbacks because those also have security implications I'm glossing over.*

Next you need the page callback function to actually send the file:

```
function mymodule_filedownload($mymodule_filename) {
   // Validate permissions
...
   // Validate filename
...
   // Load file object from database 
   $query = db_select('health_policy_document_upload_dtl', h)->fields('h')->condition('filename', $mymodule_filename,'=');
  $result = $query->execute();

   // Prep an array to hand data off to the delivery callback. It might just be the results, but often you want to tweak details...
...
  return $file_data_array;

}

function mymodule_file_deliver($file_data) {
   // Check $file_data to see if this is a valid file or an error of some kind.
...
  // Process and errors found and send proper error response.
...

  // Send file
  drupal_add_http_header("Content-length: ".$file_data['size']);
  drupal_add_http_header("Content-type: " .$file_data['type']);
  drupal_add_http_header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_data['filename']);

   print($file_data['data']);

   drupal_page_footer();
}
```

Obviously lots of details are glossed over here. In addition to hook_menu()'s documentation you likely will also want to read [`drupal_deliver_html_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7.x).  Note the use of [`drupal_add_http_header()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_add_http_header/7.x) instead of PHP's `header()`, for most basic tasks Drupal has internal functions that provide some clean up and standardization to avoid basic mistakes and conflicts with other module; you should use them whenever possible.